# Parse Total Installations and Google Play store total downloads difference

Tags: parse-platform, google-play

I am bit confused about the Parse Audience dashboard data for Android. Can someone explain me how are this calculated 
1- Daily Active Installations
2- Weekly Active Installations
3- Monthly Active Installations
4- Total Installations

Issue i am facing is that My total installations says total of 72,000 installations, whereas my Google Play store download count is about 29000.

Just wanted to know why this difference of installations between Parse and Google Play store.
Because when I send Push notification Parse Total Push send is 72000, which is very high as compared to my current Google play store users.

Thanks
Regards
Kailash M